# Custom Module and custom theme layout

Tags: magento2, module, theme-fallback

I create a small module who add a button to the `wishlist page`.
I make a file `wishlist_index_index.xml` in

```
Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Vendor_Module::css/barcode.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="customer.wishlist.buttons">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="barcode" template="Vendor_Module::wishlist/barcode.phtml"></block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Everything is working well on luma theme, my button is here.
But when I put a custom theme, the button is not present is I not copy the  wishlist_index_index.xml in my custom theme also.
I'm not sure it's the default behaviour, but in my mind you have to do it only if you want to overide the module template.

Do you know what i'm doing wrong ? i'm not very familiar with magento2 frontend...

Thanks

Comment: css is loading on wishlist page?

Comment: yes i saw my css content (and style are applied).

Comment: @Mitchum have flush cache and deploy static data after change?

Comment: yes do it already. but found it, i already override the same file but for the default magento module that's why I got this i think.